# are all polynomial equations solvable

Tags: roots

Has anyone read the Book named " Monad science" published by Lambert Academic Publishing on 28 Febuary,2014  ?http://defence.pk/threads/pakistani-student-shakeel-azam-shah%E2%80%99-book-titled%E2%80%9D-monad-science%E2%80%9D-focus-on-particle-physics.302775/  The author has made attemps to solve Beal's conjecture. Is his solution accepted? Moreover he presents a method to solve a polynomial of any degree, doesn't this coontradict with Abel–Ruffini theorem?

PS: I havn't read the book myself, this is the discription of the book..

Answer (score 9):

A solution **by radicals**? If the answer is positive the author is a crank. There exists *another* means to write the solutions of general $n$-th degree polynomial equations. If the author has found some *new* method, he can be taken seriously.

EDIT: the publisher is a vanity/scam house: http://journalology.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/lambert-academic-publishing-or-how-not.html.

EDIT2: and the title is **crankish**.

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to locate the book itself, but judging by the [description](https://www.lap-publishing.com/catalog/details//store/gb/book/978-3-8484-4136-5/monad-science):

> The unknown smallest particle of the universe is responsible for gravity, and everything in the universe must be the combination of it. These unknown particles surround bodies; their total mass (quantity of matter) must be equal to the mass of body that they surround[...]

It sounds like a crank to me.